# Change openerp 7 header/footer with rml

Tags: python, header, report, footer, odoo

I'm currently searching what is the rml file generating the header in openerp 7. I can't find it... 
I have found server/openerp/addons/base/report/corporate_defaults.xml but no... Or maybe there is a cache caching the rml befort the report generation ?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find header/footer of rml report in res_company_view.xml file server side.

The file path is : `server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_company_view.xml`

And the value of this header footer set default from:
`server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_company.py`

Regards